# link with onclick and _dopostback and jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a link (a tag) which is given an onclick event and has dopostback enabled, when generated server-side.
To this link, I later bind a jquery click event.

The onclick event has `return false;` at the end of the function and the anonymouse function binded by jquery has `return true;`

When I click on the link the jquery function is run and the postback happens, but the code in the inline onclick event is not working.

I tried flipping around the return false and return true.

When the jquery function returns false, the code works in Chrome and FF, but not IE.

When the jquery function returns true, the code works in IE, but not in FF or Chrome.

I have also tried adding the inline code to the onmouseup event, but that does not help either.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What's the reason for approaching it this way?

Comment: The link is a pager link. From the dawn of time it had some JS that would write the clicked value in a hidden field. This is working in over 30 different templates, and I do not want to change it. On the other hand, now I need to integrate web trends. Which requires adding tags to the link (which I have done) and then attaching a click event to call the WT function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but why would one ever have jQuery do one thing with a bound event then have an onclick event on the element do another.

Just use jQuery to 2 both and don't forget to use e.preventDefault() as the first line of the function.

Post the relevant code and I will try to assist further.

Comment: The reason I have both onclick and jquery events is because this happens in a custom control, which is used in many places, and I do not whish to make any breaking changes.

Comment: ah ok can you create a js fiddle with all relevant code and i will take a look